# Determine if the following set is closed under addition?

Tags: linear-algebra

$$U = \{(x,y,z,w)\in\mathbb R^4| xyw = 0\}$$

I know its closed under multiplication by a scalar but its not closed under addition, but I don't understand WHY. My teacher just says:

- $(0,1,1,1)$ is element of $U$
- $(1,0,1,1)$ is element of $U$
- $(1,1,2,2)$ is not an element of $U$

If you could explain this to me, it would be great

Comment: Your teacher has provided you with examples of elements $u$ and $u'$ of $U$ such that $u + u'$ is not an element of $U$. What more do you need to know to conclude that $U$ is not closed under addition?

Comment: I really don't understand why it's not closed under addition... I feel really dumb for not getting this.  I also have no idea what uprime stands for.

I don't even understand where (0,1,1,1) and (1,0,1,1) come from? did he just make that up. where does (1,1,2,2) come from. Why is not closed under addition. I really need an explain like i'm five from this. I"m very visual...

Comment: $(0, 1, 1, 1)$ and $(1, 0, 1, 1)$ are elements of $U$ (I called them $u$ and $u'$, but don't worry about that). Add these elements together to get$(1, 1, 2, 2)$. This is is not an element of $U$ because $1\cdot1\cdot 2 \neq 0$

Answer (score 1):

- $a = (0,1,1,1) \in U$ since $0\cdot 1 \cdot 1 = 0$
- $b = (1,0,1,1) \in U$ since $1\cdot 0 \cdot 1 = 0$
- $a + b = (0+1,1+0,1+1,1+1) = (1,1,2,2) \notin U$ since $1\cdot 1\cdot
     2 \neq 0$

Comment: Thank you! I see it now. thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

If a subspace is closed under addition, then $\forall u,u'\in U$, we have $u+u'\in U$.

This is not so in this case.

The subspace is closed under scalar multiplication, as $\forall u\in U$, $k\in\mathbb R$, we have $ku\in U$.